# How to remove items with certain length from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying for a while now to remove values for certain length from an array, an I can't seem to get it done.
I have removed white spaces and emtpy arrays using the built in functions, but I also want to remove items from the array that have less than 30 characters.

My code is:

```php
$data = array();
$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach($cells as $node) {
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        $data[] = array($child->nodeName => $child->nodeValue); 
        $data = array_map('array_filter', $data);
        $data = array_filter($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: `strlen();` function will return the character count of a string. You can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your function to something like this:

```
foreach($cells as $node){
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        // check the length is greater than or equal to 30
        if(strlen($child->nodeValue) >= 30 ){

            $data[ $child->nodeName ] =  $child->nodeValue; 

            $data[ $child->nodeName ] = array_map('array_filter', $aTempData);
            $data[ $child->nodeName ] = array_filter($aTempData);

        }
    }
}
```

If you wanted to remove from starting array you can use `unset()` as with your original method

Comment: Your welcome. You should check that getElementsByTagName doesn't return an error on no tds, if it does your not handing it

Comment: Just added a if else statement, like: if(!title) { die(); } else { //the array search }